# border color not changing on focus

Tags: html, css

The following is my code and the border isnt changing on focus, what am i doing wrong? Ive tried lots of things but nothing is working

```
<input type="text" spellcheck="false" data-placement="top" id="writeWord" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" maxlength="200" style="width: 230px;border: 0;border-bottom: 2px solid #C8C6C6;border-radius: 0;color:#6e572f;font-size:24px;font-weight:500;">

#writeWord:focus{ outline: 0; border-color:#ea6e01;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/brdrn4d3/

Comment: why all the inline styling in the input ?

Answer (score 2):

It's because the [inline styling is more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than the styling in your stylesheet.

You could use the following:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/n09sLvkn/)

```
#writeWord {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #C8C6C6;
}
#writeWord:focus {
    outline: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ea6e01;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `!important` declaration in your style :

`#writeWord:focus{ outline: 0; border-color:#ea6e01 !important;}`

But keep in mind that declaring CSS styles in a .css file is better than inline styles.